# How to use CanHub Image Cropper latest version on Java

Tags: java, android

Need help, I'm stuck at how to convert kotlin function from CanHub Image Cropper to Java.
It include two code, Activity result and the calling method

the original kotlin code is like this for the activity result:

```
private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        // use the returned uri
        val uriContent = result.uriContent
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(myActivity.contentResolver, uriContent)

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

    } else {
        // an error occurred
        val exception = result.error
    }
}
```

and this is how the calling method in kotlin:

```
cropImage.launch(
    options {
        setImageSource(
            includeGallery = true,
            includeCamera = true
        )
        setAspectRatio(150,150)
        setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
        setOutputCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
        setOutputCompressQuality(85)
    }
)
```

I try to convert the code into java since my project right now is Java and older library is not compatible with Android 11

here is my activity result converted into java, I don't know if it's the right one but at least it has no error:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<CropImageContractOptions> cropImage = registerForActivityResult(
        new CropImageContract(),
        result -> {
            Uri uriContent = result.getUriContent();
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(myActivity.getContentResolver(), uriContent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        });
```

but I'm stuck at the calling method:

```
CropImageContractOptions cropImageContractOptions = ? /* <-- what to put here?? */
cropImage.launch(cropImageContractOptions);
```

I have tried to use option but it just error unresolved variable

I have taking a look at this: [How to croping image with source just from camera with Canhub Android Image Cropper with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976279/how-to-croping-image-with-source-just-from-camera-with-canhub-android-image-crop)

But for some reason it does not even work at all for me

Is CanHub Image Cropper is not compatible with Java at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you added last version

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0"
}
```

Use this code

```
ActivityResultLauncher<CropImageContractOptions> cropImage = registerForActivityResult(new CropImageContract(), result -> {
    if (result.isSuccessful()) {
        Bitmap cropped = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result.getUriFilePath(getApplicationContext(), true));
    }
});
```

```
CropImageOptions cropImageOptions = new CropImageOptions();
cropImageOptions.imageSourceIncludeGallery = false;
cropImageOptions.imageSourceIncludeCamera = true;
CropImageContractOptions cropImageContractOptions = new CropImageContractOptions(/*pass you image uri*/, cropImageOptions);
cropImage.launch(cropImageContractOptions);
```

Comment: at first I'm confuse why I need to put Uri before even starting to take the image, but I can actually just put it null since it optional, Thanks man. it works great

Comment: I assume 1st code block to put inside onCreate method. Where should the 2nd block of code go ?

Comment: I implemented complete example here https://github.com/theshoqanebi/image-cropper-java Check it.